# FragmentStatePagerAdapter when dataset has been exhausted

Tags: android

I have a FragmentStatePagerAdapter backed by an arraylist of questions.  As the questions are answered they are removed.  Everything is working fine, but I would like to display a different message when the questions are done.  Is there a way to do this in the FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty trivial to do. Just make sure `getCount()` always returns 1 if the list is empty, and if the list of questions is empty, display the empty fragment. Just call `notifyDatasetChanged()` after removing a question.

```
class QuestionsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Question> mQuestionsList;

    QuestionsAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Question> questionsList) {
        super(fm);
        mQuestionsList = new ArrayList<>(questionsList);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        if (mQuestionsList.isEmpty()) {
            // Return your special Fragment if the list is empty
            return EmptyQuestionsFragment.newInstance();
        } else {
            // Otherwise, business as usual
            return QuestionsFragment.newInstance(mQuestionsList.get(i));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Always return 1 item, even if the list is empty.
        return Math.max(1, mQuestionsList.size());
    }
}
```